# How do you say 'Dear John,' in German?

Tags: formality, letter

I understand that it's Sehr geehrte Frau Marie for females, Sehr geehrter Herr John for males, Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren for Dear Sir/Madam.

But what is 'Dear (name)' such as 'Dear John,' or 'Dear Marie,'?

I'm looking for the unisex version that would be used in formal letters such as:

'Dear Charlie, how are you?'...
Charlie in this case is difficult to determine whether it's a male or female.

Comment: In your first example "Sehr geehrter Herr John", is *John* for you a surname or a family name? - If it is a surname, your proposition is wrong as you would never write "Sehr geehrter Herr" + surname. "Sehr geehrte/r Herr/Frau" goes always with the family name. - Note that "John" is a possible family name in German speaking countries, pronounced however iooooon (not dzhonn).

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5079/how-do-i-reply-to-an-email-using-salutation-if-a-gender-is-unknown and also  https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13735/how-do-germans-refer-to-people-without-caring-about-the-gender

Comment: I don't recognize the the benefit of a *unisex* addressing, if a specific person and name is following. If *sehr geehrte(r)* is too formal, one could resort to *Guten Tag* or *Hallo* or to *liebe(r)* if communication is on first name basis.

Comment: also related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25/in-what-context-do-we-write-guten-tag-rather-than-sehr-geehrte-damen-und-herr

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: I think you mean a *given name* instead of a *surname*. A surname *is* a family name (at least in German names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ususal translation of "dear" is "lieber" (male) or "liebe" (female), and I can confirm that this adjective is actually used in German correspondence if one wants to use a less formal tone. The problem with this is the same as with "Sehr geehrte/r" and with any other adjective: The male and the female forms differ.

You can use "Liebe/r Charlie" but that somewhat defeats the familiarity of "Liebe"/"Lieber".

If you want an informal unisex way of addressing people you can use "Hallo" or "Guten Tag" as already suggested in the comments. The former is very informal.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt keine Unisex-Anrede in der Einzahl im Deutschen, weil es keine geschlechtslosen Substantive gibt.

Selbst wenn ein sächliches Generikum vorläge, wie

```
Liebes Mitglied
```

ist das sprachlich ein Geschlecht, das sächliche nämlich.

```
Liebe Charlie oder lieber Charlie
```

wäre eine formale Fluchtmöglichkeit, aber die Unkenntnis, ob es sich um eine Frau oder einen Mann handelt dementiert die Nähe, die das 'Liebe/Lieber' vermitteln will. Bei einer unpersönlichen Anrede ist es aber auch nicht besser; auch da wirken zwei alternative Formen unglücklich.

In einem sehr informellen Kontext kann man sich in ein unverbindliches "Hallo" flüchten:

```
Hallo Charlie,
```

Comment: Ergänzung: Die Anrede "Hallo" wird insbesondere in E-Mail-Kommunikation auch im geschäftlichen Umfeld (Behörden, Firmen, etc.  immer üblicher: "Hallo Herr Müller, vielen Dank für Ihre Nachricht von gestern abend. Wir haben... "

Comment: Ich habe - kein Scherz - auch schon Einladungen von Partei-Ortsvereinen gesehen an: "Liebe Mitglieder und Mitgliederinnen".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Besser als „Liebe Mitglieder und Ohneglieder“. *duck*

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann „Es gibt keine Unisex-Anrede in der Einzahl im Deutschen, weil es keine geschlechtslosen Substantive gibt.“ Stimmt das? Ja, es gibt keine geschlechtslosen Substantive, aber Unisex bezieht sich auf das biologische Geschlecht einer Person, und zwischen den beiden besteht keine Verbindung.

Comment: Wenn du also jemanden mit „Mein Schatz“ ansprichst, kann damit sowohl ein Mann als auch eine Frau gemeint sein. Dass *Schatz* ein Maskulinum ist, spielt dabei keine Rolle.

Comment: @Philipp: Genau das ist gemeint.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich würde aber jmd. der sprachlich unsicher ist nicht dazu ermutigen, selbst mit dem "Hallo" anzufangen. Wahrscheinlich bin ich da zu vorsichtig u. zurückhaltend.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more difficult to preface correspondence in German because most of it will be gendered. At the least, if you aren't comfortable with "Herr/Frau Charlie" then you can write "An Charlie" (ein Brief an Charlie, in Akkusativ) which really should have the first and last name.

This is more something you'd put on a letter so others know that it isn't meant for them, but it works for your purpose.

In my correspondence, I generally use "Herr/Frau jdm." unless it is very obvious. At the very worst, I just put their full name.